# version code shows different, from app grade file version code, when uploading to app store as aab

Tags: android, react-native, apk, android-app-bundle

When uploading an aab to the android play store console the versionCode is showing a much higher and completely different number than expected.
The version Code is not showing as written in the gradle (targetSdkVersion) file of the app like it does when uploaded as a single apk.

I've built several apks in the past. I wanted to decrease apk size for users. to accomplish this I've built my app as an aab and successfully uploaded the file into firebase console.
The problem manifests itself at this point. Thought the bundle is successfully uploaded, the version code is incorrect and I would like it to match the desired gradle version number

build.gradle

```
   defaultConfig {...
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 27
        versionName "3.0.9"
    }
...


after uploading aab version code shows: 3145755
expecting version code: 27
```

Comment: Double check thag this is the right build.gradle file (from the main "app" module) and that you're executing the right tasks. Also check that you don't have any post-processing that modifies the versionCode. There is no difference between an APK and an App Bundle in that regard.

Comment: @Pierre, I can't find anything that would cause this. I just took another look through all the code in android studio and did a global search for the number 3145755 and nothing comes up. before I build the version code is set correctly everywhere I look. After I build the aab if I 'analyze' the app then, within the manifest, is set incorrectly.

Comment: How do you analyze the manifest of the bundle? Try running the command `java -jar bundletool-all.jar dump manifest --bundle bundle.aab --xpath /manifest/@android:versionCode`

Comment: Good news, figured it out. Thanks @Pierre. I'll post as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that worked. It turns out not only was the aab not getting the right version code, but neither were the apks.
somewhere along the way this code had been changed in the app build.gradle file:

- Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
- - An APK that only works on ARM devices
- - An APK that only works on x86 devices
- The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
- Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
- the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
  */
  def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = true   <------------------- (should be false)

so there you have it. don't set that to true whatever you do.